# Display This Bootstrap Modal on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have the following Bootstrap modal...

HTML:

```
<div id="tallModal" class="modal modal-wide fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

CSS:

```
.modal.modal-wide .modal-dialog {
  width: 90%;
}
.modal-wide .modal-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".modal-wide").on("show.bs.modal", function() {
  var height = $(window).height() - 200;
  $(this).find(".modal-body").css("max-height", height);
});
```

Here it is on CodePen: https://codepen.io/TomAshley/pen/wPxBjB

How can I get the modal to display as soon as the page loads? My attempt of this is using `window.load` as you can see here:

```
$(window).load("show.bs.modal", function() {
        var height = $(window).height() - 200;
        $(this).find(".modal-body").css("max-height", height);
    });
```

But it doesn't popup the modal. How to make it pop on page load?

Comment: I didn't think I was supposed to use the id for my example. That's why I asked.

Comment: It'll work with a class too, just might get a duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trigger the modal programatically

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tallModal').modal('show');
});
```

Here is the [pen](https://codepen.io/sygn/pen/QOBwZK)

Comment: Or it can be `$('.modal-wide').modal('show');` , right? Thanks

Comment: yes, you changed only the selector but it matches the same element, id(#) is safer

Comment: For some reason in my design when I add this, the modal width is much smaller. Any idea how can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario we can use

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var height = $(window).height() - 200;
   $(this).find(".modal-body").css("max-height", height);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question...